# Do you need to buy or build a CTI adapter for CTI functionality?

Tags: opencti, cti

We want to connect our Salesforce org with our Avaya Workplace telephony system. I find the documentation of both Avaya and Salesforce less then helpful. Avaya's documentation is lacking and Salesforce's documentation is confusing.

Case in point, [Salesforce's documentation on OpenCTI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_intro.htm): "To display CTI functionality in Salesforce, Open CTI uses browsers as clients. With Open CTI, you can make calls from a softphone directly in Salesforce without installing CTI adapters on your machines."

That sounds great, Avaya offers several (why???) Chrome browser plugins that promise to connect Salesforce and Avaya.

But the Salesforce documentation continues: "After you develop an Open CTI implementation, you can integrate it with Salesforce using Salesforce Call Center."

Wow, wait. Now we need to develop something? Isn't an Avaya browser plugin sufficient? I cannot find any documentation on the Avaya browser plugins, by the way. So far I found [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/avaya-ix-workplace/klbodegekkpgiplaadabcmepfpcbeheg?hl=en) and [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/avaya-communicator-for-we/pjkjihhnegikngnamahchimifhdlfhkm?hl=en).

In short, I would like to know what is the bare minimum we need to connect Salesforce to an Avaya Workplace telephone system, so that we can receive and place calls inside Salesforce using a softphone. We use Lightning Experience on a Sales Cloud license (not Service Cloud).

Comment: OpenCTI is Salesforce's plugin architecture. If one were to develop a client of a telephony system that will run as a web component inside Salesforce, OpenCTI is what one might use. Telephony vendors provide their own clients that do not conform to OpenCTI. A non-OpenCTI client accomplishes the same goal of having a user connect to a telephony service but without tight integration into Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

You need a 'Salesforce Compatible Avaya CTI Adoptor built as per OpenCTI standards'. This is something that you will have to BUY from either Avaya or any 3rd Party Vendor.